# Создать массив параметров

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пробую использовать библиотеку [bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com). Вопрос заключается в том, как динамически создавать параметры функции. Например, как сформировать массив опций `inputOptions` на основе какого-то своего массива в цикле. Ну, например, есть json

`[
   {"id":"2","language":"ENG","language_full":"Английский"},
   {"id":"1","language":"RU","language_full":"Русский"}
 ]`

И как из него получить что-то пригодное для вставки в `inputOptions` (смотри ниже)?

```
    {
        text: 'Русский',
        value: 1,
    },
    {
        text: 'Английский',
        value: 2,
    },
```

Вот пример функции библиотеки bootbox.js

```
bootbox.prompt({
    title: "This is a prompt with select!",
    inputType: 'select',
    inputOptions: [
        {
            text: 'Choose one...',
            value: '',
        },
        {
            text: 'Choice One',
            value: '1',
        },
        {
            text: 'Choice Two',
            value: '2',
        },
        {
            text: 'Choice Three',
            value: '3',
        }
    ],
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен, что понял вопрос, но наверное как-то так:

```js
var json = [
    {"id":"2","language":"ENG","language_full":"Английский"},
    {"id":"1","language":"RU","language_full":"Русский"}
  ],
  options = [];

for(let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  options.push({
    text: json[i].language_full,
    value: json[i].id
  });
}

console.log(options);
```